# Xamarin Forms FFImageLoading SVG Is blending possible without SkiaSharp?

Tags: xamarin, svg, xamarin.forms, skiasharp, ffimageloading

Is it possible to blend SVG images that use `FFImageLoadingSVG`.

I need to blend a SVG image that I loaded to make up a whole image but I cannot use `Opacity` as it doesn't do what I need it to do. Blending is required and I don't think this is possible.

Is there a way to combine Blending from Skia sharp and FFImageLoading together inside XAML so I do not have to write any back code and have a re-usable XAML code for this?

Current XAML code.

```
<svg:SvgCachedImage Source="resource://uCue_Silver.Resources.SVGs.star_m.svg"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Scale="1">
    <svg:SvgCachedImage.Transformations>
        <fftransformations:TintTransformation HexColor="#FFFFFF"
                                                EnableSolidColor="True" />
    </svg:SvgCachedImage.Transformations>
</svg:SvgCachedImage>
<svg:SvgCachedImage Source="resource://uCue_Silver.Resources.SVGs.star_m.svg"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Scale="0.8">
    <svg:SvgCachedImage.Transformations>
        <fftransformations:TintTransformation HexColor="#FFFF00"
                                                EnableSolidColor="True" />
    </svg:SvgCachedImage.Transformations>
</svg:SvgCachedImage>
<svg:SvgCachedImage Source="resource://uCue_Silver.Resources.SVGs.s2.svg"
                    WidthRequest="200"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    ScaleX="-0.8"
                    ScaleY="0.8">
    <svg:SvgCachedImage.Transformations>
        <fftransformations:TintTransformation HexColor="#FFFFFF"
                                                EnableSolidColor="True" />
    </svg:SvgCachedImage.Transformations>
</svg:SvgCachedImage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not believe there's a way to achieve this in Xamarin.

However, you could use Illustrator, or even a free software like gimp, to open your multiple path/svg images, and then combine then into a single path (Merge Visible Paths).

At that point you could then have multiple svg in your Xamarin app of the separate svg, and the combined one as well.